# Unable to make calls, but MMS/USSD and SMS works

Tags: calls, motorola-moto-g, dialer-codes, ussd

I am running a [Moto G Stylus 2021](https://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_g_stylus_(2021)-10583.php).
Currently, I am not able to make any phone calls, not even access my voicemail. I am though, able to receive phone calls and make and receive text messages and use USSD codes. I do not know why this is happening as it did not happen before. It is not a carrier issue because I reached out to them and they told me that they have detected no issues with my device but either way sent out a SIM refresh to my device. Even so I was still unable to make phone calls.

Recent changes to my phone was someone going in and messing around with the MMI codes and settings.
Does anyone know what may be the issue?

Comment: Have you reached out to your carrier? This sounds more like a carrier issue than a phone  issue.

Comment: @acejavelin It's not a carrier issue as the first thing I did was contact them and spoke with them for a good amount of time about the issue I was experiencing. But in the end they couldn't find out what the problem was, unfortunately.

Comment: At this point we don't know what is wrong and I can' think of anything that would cause no outbound calls but everything else including receiving them works. Try a Network Settings Reset, and if that fails consider removing the SIM, doing a factory reset, then setup and reinsert SIM. I know it's annoying, but I don't know what could have changed that could cause that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it seems as if my carrier has issues with the caller ID. Typing in `*31#` breaks phone calls, and seems to enable some form of outgoing call barring.

Typing in `#31#` seems to disable it and allow me to make phone calls once more.